# TYPO3 and CDN setup

Tags: cdn, typo3

I am trying to figure out how to setup CDN for a TYPO3 website and I have some
questions regarding it.

I have created 3 subdomains:

```
cdn.domain.com  - typo3temp
cdn1.domain.com - fileadmin
cdn2.domain.com - typo3conf
```

Do I need to move/copy the folders from the root folder on domain.com to the httpdocs on each of these subdomains or will TYPO3 fetch the static content from the root directory
on domain.com and how to do it?

I am trying to use it with ja_replacer and httpconnection - none of them seems to work, so I am doing something completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it it solved by symlinking it directory to the subdomain to be used and the ja_replacer to replace all path in the FE ouput and it works perfectly.